# git-stash changes without reverting

Tags: git, git-stash

I work on a project using Git. Every once in a while I find myself wanting to save my changes, without committing them, just as a backup, and then continue working. What I usually do is `git stash` and then immediately `git stash apply` to bring the code back to the same state as before stashing. The problem I have with this is that git stash reverts my work directory so even though I apply the stash immediately files and projects have to be rebuilt because they appear to have changed. This is quite annoying because some of our projects take ages to build.

So my question is, is there a way to stash my changes without reverting? If stash doesn't do that, is there any other command in git that can do it? Thank you.

Comment: As an alternative, you could also `git add` the changes and simply not commit them. This places the changed files into the staging area. To revert to the staged version, use `git checkout -- <filename>`.

Comment: @Phillip I will give it a try, thanks!

Comment: There's definitely no perfect solution. What I tend to do in cases like this is just go ahead and make many commits, then squish them together later. (Usually this means making a new branch as well—I end up with a *lot* of branches sometimes :-) .)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I posted this question I was new to git and didn't understand its power in full. Now I realize that stashing is not what I needed and that git's local branches do the job much better.

Assume you are on main_branch, which you want to keep clean from experimental changes.

Simply create a new branch in order to store your experimental changes.

```
git checkout -b temp_branch
```

Assume you do some changes and want to save your progress. Simply commit, nothing to worry about, it's all on the temp_branch:

```
git commit -a -m "first change"
```

Assume you do some more changes and want to store again:

```
git commit -a -m "second change"
```

Finally, assume you are happy with your experimental changes and want to merge them to the main branch. There are two cases:

1) If you want to merge all changes, do:

```
git fetch . temp_branch:main_branch
```

This brings all changes of temp_branch into the main_branch, without switching to the main branch, which means your files are not modified and no recompilation is required. Note it's possible only if you haven't done any other changes on main_branch in the meantime. If main_branch has changed you need to use `git merge` or `git rebase`, but this scenario is beyond what the question is asking.

2) Assume you want to merge only some of the commits of temp_branch into main_branch. You can do this with `git cherry-pick`. First do `git checkout main_branch` to switch to the main_branch (this modifies the files but this is inevitable since you are dropping some of your changes), then do `git cherry-pick <SHA>` (where `<SHA>` is the hash of the commit you want to merge). You can see the list of commits by doing `git log temp_branch`. Note that merging only some of the changes might give conflicts which you 'll need to resolve.

Comment: I had the same question as you. Thanks for posting this answer. I don't think this approach is really equivalent to `git stash` plus `git stash apply` though, because it doesn't preserve changes in the index separately from those in the working directory. Maybe it would be equivalent if you didn't use `commit -a`... I don't remember how `checkout -b` works with a dirty working directory and index.

Answer (score 8):

This can be achieved by manually creating a stash commit object, then storing it in the stash.

```sh
git stash store $(git stash create) -m "Stash commit message"
```

### Explanation

I too like throwing things into the stash as a rollback point, before proceeding with a change or refactoring that I feel might not pan out.  I find that throwing it onto the stash with a brief description is quicker, easier, and requires less mental context switching than using a branch does.  Using a branch involves creating the branch, remembering the branch name, and then deleting the interim branch commit and the branch it self when resuming.

Git has commands to store things into the stash without removing the files from the working directory, as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44330944/1108305.  A stash commit object can be created with `git stash create` and then saved to the stash using `git stash store`:

```sh
git stash store $(git stash create) -m "Stash commit message"
```

This can be saved to a Git alias to make it more convenient:

```sh
git config --global alias.stash-keep '!git stash store $(git stash create)'

git stash-keep -m "Stash commit message"
```

Note that this does not do *everything* that `git stash push` does.  For one, it does not append the branch name to the commit, e.g. "`stash@{0}: On myBranch: Stash commit message`".  Secondly, the above simple alias will error with "`"git stash store" requires one <commit> argument`" instead of "`No local changes to save`" when there are no changes to stash.  Those limitations could be addressed with a more complex alias or script, though the minimal version provided here will likely be sufficient.

Comment: This perfectly answers the original question.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
git stash && git stash apply
```

And in case you prefer your stash with a comment:

```
git stash save “stash comment” && git stash apply
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From a quick test I did, it looks like the changes are stashed and reapplied, modifying the file in the process and causing recompilation. My motivation with this was to avoid file modification and recompilation.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want a way to temporarily store your changes so that you don't accidentally delete them, can roll back.

The best way to do it is to actually commit your changes locally anyway.

Typical workflow is like so:

```
vim myfile # make some changes
git add myfile
git commit -m "temp changes 1"
vim myfile # make more changes
git commit --amend
git diff HEAD~1 # See the changes you've made compared to last HEAD.
```

The downside with this is that your "local changes" aren't revisioned.

The other alternative is to just keep on saving your local work as distinct commits and then simply squashing them for the sake of polish before sending out a patch/PR.

This will look something like this:

```
vim myfile2 # make changes
git add myfile2
git commit -m "temp changes dated X"
vim myfile2 # more changes
git add myfile2
git commit -m "temp changes dated Y"
```

Then simply do something like this, before sending them away.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~N # Where N is the number of local commits you made
# Squash them, by changing 'pick' to 'squash' in your editor.
# Send them away
git push origin dev
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do what I wanted. My local files are still reverted.

Comment: I think that you misunderstood OP's question. His problem is that `git stash`/`git apply` changes the files' mtime, not that it unstages changes that were already added to the index.

Comment: I think understood his question correctly, what I didn't know was that `git stash save --keep index` still modified the `c/mtime`.

Comment: What OP could alternatively do (and I admit this is a terrible hack), is to commit the files anyway, then do subsequent "saves" with `git commit --amend` and then a final `git commit --amend` or `git rebase -i HEAD~1` to add some finishing touches before sending off the commit/patch/PR. But it should ideally get the job done. This is something mercurial queues do very well iirc :/

Comment: Thank you. Sounds like an option. However what I like about not commiting, is that at any time I can do a diff and see what are my changes across the whole repository. If I commit, it will be harder to diff and see my changes.

Comment: You will have to do `git diff HEAD~1` instead, but other than that, not too difficult. :)

Comment: There is another issue, `--keep-index` only works with changes that were already `git add`'ed.

Comment: @ffledgling I will have to try this later. Thanks :)

Comment: @Phillip you're right, I'm doing to remove that answer and add the new one.

Comment: @ffledgling I tried the workflow you described, and it is pretty much what I want. I have my back up, plus I can see all my changes with git diff HEAD~1. Just one clarification. You write 'The downside with this is that your "local changes" aren't revisioned'. What do we mean by "aren't revisioned"? Sorry I am fairly new to git!

Comment: @user779446 when you make a change, then save it, then make some more changes, then save it again. They get merged into one big change with `git commit --amend`, so essentially your local changes themselves have no git history, which is okay most times, but some people don't like that.

Comment: @ffledgling I see. Not a problem in my case. Thanks again!