# What are the plumbing commands to do a git stash , git checkout mybranch, git stash pop?

Tags: git

I would like to create a script that does the following:
1) git stash
2) git checkout myBranch
3) git stash pop

What are the git plumbing commands that could replace the above git porcelain commands?

**Edit:**

Based on the very detailed and lengthy (thank you guys) answers of Mark Adelsberger and Torek I will stick to use the porcelain commands. I would also like to note the following statement which I found very helpful on when to use porcelain vs plumbing commands.

Quoted from  Mark Adelsberger' s answer :

*"Since the commands you're using don't produce output that would drive your script, I wouldn't worry too much about finding plumbing equivalents."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it's worth a quick reminder that the way `git stash save` works is that it makes a new commit—or really, at least two commits, but one of them is kind of a primary one and that's the hash ID one uses to work with it from then on.  So we can refer to this as "the stash commit": it's just like any other commit except that (a) it's on *no* branch, and (b) it looks like a merge commit, but should never be used as a merge commit.

The `git stash` command itself is a *very* complicated script that has no direct plumbing equivalent.  However, it does (since Git 1.8.4) have its own way to be *used as* plumbing, via `git stash create` (optionally followed by `git stash store` to assign the stash commit a name).

The create step makes the stash commit that `git stash save` would make, but does not assign it a `stash@{number}` entry, so that all the existing stashes are named in the usual way.  Note that just like `git stash save`, it does *nothing at all* if there is nothing to stash.  The output from `git stash save` is the hash ID of the new primary stash commit, or nothing at all if there is no new commit.

If this creates a stash commit, you have 14 days (by default) to give it a name or finish using it.  If you expect your command sequence to take more than 14 days, you might want to use `git stash store` to push it onto the stash stack as `stash@{0}`, renumbering all the others up one.  If you think your script will finish within the 14 day grace period, you don't even need to invent a name: you can just pass the stash commit hash to `git stash apply`.

Hence:

```
commit=$(git stash create)
... do your thing here ...
if [ "$commit" != "" ]; then git stash apply $commit; fi
```

(as [Mark Adelsberger noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44330729/1256452) you should check whether the `apply` succeeded, and if not, you should probably give the stash commit a name).

As for `git checkout`, the plumbing equivalent is a bit complicated (it consists of atomically determining whether the checkout will succeed, and then if so, using `git symbolic-ref` to re-bind `HEAD` while using `git read-tree` and `git checkout-index` to update the index and work-tree to match the new `HEAD` commit, preserving index and work-tree modifications that can be preserved).  If you've just done a successful `git stash save` or equivalent, the only remaining failure cases occur when:

- there are untracked files (files in the work-tree but not in the index) that will become tracked by switching commits, or
- there are files in the index with either `--skip-worktree` or `--assume-unchanged` set, that will be changed in the index (and hence in the work-tree) by switching commits

so it's *almost* possible to reduce this to some simple plumbing commands.  But `git checkout branchname` is designed to be *usable as* plumbing anyway.  You probably might as well just use it.

Comment: Huh... I never noticed this: why *does* git use multiple parents for the WIP commit?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Mostly, so that it can find them easily. The U commit exists iff there is a `^3` parent; the I commit is the `^2` parent and the commit that was `HEAD` when the stash was made is the `^1` parent. The stash script could have done "I then W" with optional second parent for U, perhaps, but I think maybe whoever wrote it wanted to make sure it didn't treat any two ordinary non-merge commits as a stash, so making sure they look like merges gives a little bit of safety. Of course there are other ways they could have made it even-more-safe, eg, using an empty-tree-commit as a parent.

Answer (score 2):

Since the commands you're using don't produce output that would drive your script, I wouldn't worry too much about finding plumbing equivalents.  You would want to be aware of the possibility that the stash doesn't apply cleanly, I suppose...

If you do decide to use plumbing, I think you're in for a workout.  I can't locate any "intermediate level" plumbing commands, so I think you'll have to go to basics...

And there are several ways to look at that.  If you want to be faithful to the way `stash` works: A stash is two or three commits, plus a ref with a manipulated reflog.  For your purposes you might choose to steer clear of the `stash` ref, but you'd want to do *something* to provide access to the "stashed" changes in the event the apply step fails.

So what you'd do is something like:

- the current commit is `H`; your target branch head is `T`
- create a commit `I` with the index state
- stage the changes to tracked files in the working tree
- create a commit `W`, whose parent is `I`
- if emulating the `--untracked` or `--all` options: stage the untracked files (including ignored files in the case of `--all`) and create another commit 'U' whose parent is `W`
- Somehow make note of the ID for `U` (or `W` if you didn't create `U`); this is what the `stash` ref is for in the porcelain commands
- Do a hard reset to `H` (which is still `HEAD` unless you moved `HEAD` as a side-effect of creating those other commits)

Ok, now you've created a "stash".  Next you need to effectively rebase from `U` (or `W`), with upstream `H`, `--onto T`.  To stay in plumbing land, I guess you could use commands to create and apply patches.  Let's say you get `T -- I' -- W'' (and maybe` -- U'`) out of this.

- checkout `U'` (or `W'`)
- reset mixed-mode to `I'`
- reset soft to `T`

And then whatever clean-up makes sense.  Now, like I said, that's if you're trying to stay (needlessly?) faithful to the way `stash` works.  You probably could generate the patches for the index and WIP without going through temporary commits, clean the work tree back to `HEAD` state, check out `T`, apply the index patch, `add` everything, apply the WIP patch.  But that's still a lot of work and you now have to figure out how to preserve the patch files for the user in the event the patch apply process doesn't go smoothly.

Seriously, I know it's bad mojo and all, but I'd just use `stash`

Comment: Whereas the info I've given is a relatively literal answer to your question, @torek has - as often the case - remembered details of command options I had forgotten. His practical advice is more complete than mine, so you might want to switch to that as the accepted answer.