# Is there a way to stash the current git index, `git add -u`, and then restore the index to the stashed state?

Tags: git, git-stash

The idea here is that I want to (temporarily) stage all pending changes, then later undo it, without ever changing files in the working tree.  It seems like it should be in the domain of `git stash`, but I can't figure out how to make it happen using that command.  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding but is `git stash save` not sufficient since that will stash all pending changes and return to last commit

Comment: Just running `git reset` will unstage files from the index without making changes to the work tree.

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60555832/7976758 ?

Comment: @phd sure, that's how I can grab an initial snapshot of the working copy+index state.  But the challenge is how to roll back to that state after `git add -u` *without changing any files in the working copy*.

Comment: @larsks, sure, but AFAIK `git reset` will unstage *all* the files (and all the changes in those files).  Before starting this operation, imagine there are some changes in the index, and some in the working copy, but not in the index.  The goal is to move all the latter changes into the index, and then roll that back by moving *only those changes* out of the index.

Comment: @Schwern my project has a pre-commit hook that lints *only* the staged file states, but then writes fixes into the files without staging them.  I don't have the power to change this system, but I find it extremely error-prone.  What I really want is for that whole automatic cleanup process to happen before I build, so I'm trying to put it at the head of my personal build script. But I want it to clean up *all* the changes in my working copy, not just the ones I've already staged.  And I'd like to do all this without changing what I've staged. So I need to `git add -u`, run the hook, then undo.

Comment: Note, I don't want to change any files in the working copy, even temporarily, because I don't want to trigger spurious rebuilds.

Comment: I dislike client hooks, they just get in the way. "*I don't have the power to change this system*" Sure you do, it's `.git/hooks/pre-commit` in your cloned copy. Delete it, or edit out the linting part. Seems silly to fight it. Do the linting in your editor or build script.

Comment: @Schwern good point; I *could* change it.  I just wouldn't be using the prescribed set-up and I'd need to make sure to keep my editor or build script in sync with the project's (they currently do about 15 different passes using a tool called pre-commit).

Comment: @DaveAbrahams Perhaps you could get the linting part of the hook extracted into a stand-alone piece which could be shared by the hook and your build script.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: regarding [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66466799/is-there-a-way-to-stash-the-current-git-index-git-add-u-and-then-restore-th/66468933?noredirect=1#comment117535490_66466799):

> @phd sure, that's how I can grab an initial snapshot of the working copy+index state. But the challenge is how to roll back to that state after `git add -u` *without changing any files in the working copy*.

For reference, the `@phd` here is looking at an answer involving a `git stash store` of the result of a `git stash create`.  The `git stash create` operation first creates two trees: one is the result of `git write-tree` (as outlined below), and the other is *in effect* the result of copying the index to a temporary index, running `git add -u`, and then running `git write-tree` again, all using the temporary index.  These two trees—if they're written at all; `git stash create` does nothing when your index and working tree are both "clean"—are then wrapped up into the `I` and `W` commits described in [the `git stash` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), and `git stash create` prints the hash ID of the `W` commit (suitable for use with `git stash store`).

Note that your working tree is *not disturbed* by this part of the operation.  There is nothing to restore.  What disturbs your working tree is the `git reset` step of `git stash push`.  But `git stash create` does not run this step!  It just makes the `I` and `W` commits.  So if that's all you want, `git stash create` will get you what you want.

> my project has a pre-commit hook that lints only the staged file states ...

In this case, why not:

- make the `W` commit (use `git stash create` if you like), then
- optionally, give that a temporary branch name just for sanity purposes, then
- use `git worktree add` to check out that branch, or that commit as a detached-HEAD, then
- run the pre-commit hook over the added work-tree.

If the linter is really well behaved, you could perhaps skip the added worktree entirely and just set `GIT_INDEX_FILE` to a temporary file into which you read the tree from the `W` commit, and run the linter with that `GIT_INDEX_FILE` setting in place.

[Edit 2:] If the linter is *really* well behaved—few of them seem to be this well-behaved—you should be able to just set `GIT_INDEX_FILE` to a temporary file, run `git add -u`, run the linter, and then remove the temporary file.  Of course it might be even easier to run the linter over the working tree, rather than over an index.  That requires a pre-commit linter that is flexible: it can either use a working tree (ignoring the existence of Git entirely) in the style of older, dumber, non-Git-aware linters; *or* use a Git index.  This would be a lot faster and easier overall.

[original answer below line]

---

I think we have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/641754) here, but just to answer the question as asked:

- there's no point as there is only one index; but
- you can temporarily use a temporary index; and
- you can literally do that, it's just pointless.

The way Git uses the index is complicated, so there are many rough edges here.  You could cut yourself on any of them.  For instance, the index could have assume-unchanged and/or skip-worktree bits set on particular entries, or could be in the expanded state that Git uses in the middle of a conflicted merge (including cherry-pick, revert, and rebase operations).  But in general, the index can be turned into one of Git's internal *tree objects* at almost any time using `git write-tree`:

```sh
hash=$(git write-tree) || echo "unable to turn index into a tree"
```

This write-tree operation fails if the index is in the expanded, unmerged state; otherwise, it succeeds, even if there are some flag bits set.  If it succeeds, `hash` now contains the hash ID of a tree object.  This tree object will live on in the repository for at least 14 days by default, so you have up to 14 days to create a commit that uses it, or otherwise link to it with a tag or some other reference, which will keep it alive more permanently.

Having *written out* the index *as* a tree, you can now do anything you like to the index, including running `git add -u`.  Later, you can restore the index to the state it has in that saved tree using `git read-tree`:

```sh
git read-tree $hash || echo "unable to restore index"
```

The read-tree operation can fail in various cases; consult [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree).  Some flags make some operations succeed or fail when they might otherwise fail or succeed respectively, and you can also completely empty the index first, then read into it, for instance.

To use a *temporary* index, set the environment variable `GIT_INDEX_FILE` to the name of the temporary index file.  This file must either not exist at all, or be a valid index file.  An empty file (as made by `mktemp` for instance) is not suitable.  You can, however, use:

```sh
TF=$(mktemp) || exit
rm -f $TF                     # remove it now
trap "rm -f $TF" 0 1 2 3 15   # arrange to remove it on exit or signal
export GIT_INDEX_FILE=$TF     # point Git at this name from here on
```

in sh or bash scripts.  (Use a similar construct in whatever language you like.)  Operations will now create an index and fill it in, using the temporary file, so you can now fiddle with that, without affecting the real index.  Run Git commands with `GIT_INDEX_FILE` unset to use the real index, and with `GIT_INDEX_FILE=$TF` to use the temporary index:

```sh
git read-tree --empty        # create empty $TF index file
echo "temp index contents:"
git ls-files --stage

echo "real index contents:"
(unset GIT_INDEX_FILE; git ls-files --stage)

# back to using the temporary index in $TF
```

for instance will demonstrate the effect.  The last line uses a subshell so as to unset the environment variable for the duration of the final `git ls-files`, but retain the environment variable in the mainline execution, for whatever commands come after the final comment.

As always, temporary objects created for whatever purpose—including any blobs you might put in the temporary index—have that 14-day grace period to turn into real commits.  After that, `git gc` might remove them, even if you are not yet done with them.

Comment: I'm sorry you went to that much effort to write a long explanation.  I must not have asked my question very well, but believe me, I really do understand how git works and what the index is and all that.